# Django custom decorator for custom permission

Tags: django, permissions, python-decorators

There is a `Project` model with a ManyToMany relation to `User` model, using a join table.
If a user is not member of a project (not in the join table), I want to prevent the user from accessing a view that shows the specific project.

I know it could be solved with a simple if statement inside the view method or a custom filter in the template, but I would like to be able to do this with a custom decorator. 
Is this possible? If so how could it be done?

Something like:

```
def may_user_view_this(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.user
        project = Project.objects.get(id=???????) #id
        if not project.has_user(user):
            return HttpResponse('You cannot view this.')
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@may_user_view_this() # if not go the specific url
def my_view(request, page_id=None):
    # do stuff and render
```

How can I access the parameter `page_id` sent to `my_view` from the decorator function?

Comment: Yes, this is possible.